# Google scholar change main version of paper?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I have an article on google scholar that was published with an open source journal and also put on arxiv, however google merged these two and sees the arxiv version as the main one and therefore messes up the citation.

Is this something that can be changed?

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Investigations+into+the+origin+of+Einstein%E2%80%99s+Sink&btnG=&oq=Investigations+into+the+origin+of+Einstein%27s+Sink

Comment: We don’t run or have any control over google scholar. Have you contacted the help desk?

Comment: I am quite interested in this too. I did not find a satisfactory answer yet to do this.

Answer (score 8):

Choose the `Unmerge` option to split them into two separate articles. Afterwards, you can select both articles and merge them again. At that point, scholar will ask which one should be considered the main publication.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations on publishing with the open access journal *Studium*, the journal looks very nice.

I believe you *can* unmerge the bibliographic records for this item at Google Scholar.

1. Go to your Google Scholar profile and make sure you're logged-in
2. Click on the paper title in question which should be in blue e.g. "Investigations into the origin of Einstein's Sink" once clicked it'll bring up a new sub-window
3. At the top right-hand corner of this sub-window you'll see two buttons. One is to edit the record, the other is to delete the record. Click the edit button
4. Choose the very bottom option to unmerge the record. (screenshot below is the final screen you should see which offers the unmerge option)

[image: Unmerge Google Scholar record]

Comment: If I correctly understand the question, what is wanted is not to unmerge, in the sense of making two publications out of one, but rather to have the published version be the primary one, so that people who lookup this paper on Google scholar will cite the published version rather than the arXiv preprint.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is change what displays your google scholar profile manually (it won't affect the meta data of any articles, citations etc ..) in this page:

[image]

At the bottom, tick "Keep this article as it is now"

Google scholar will keep the arxiv version as main, but will display what you entered under article name. I had the same problem and now :

[image]

EDIT : It only changes it in your google scholar profile, not when you look for the article from the google scholar search :/

Comment: It did not solve the original issue asked my the author of this question

Answer (score 0):

In addition to editing your Google Scholar profile, you may also want to update the front page of your Arxiv pre-print to indicate that you want people to cite the published version of the article. And you can include a copy of the reference. Some pre-print servers also allow you to explicitly link to the peer-reviewed version of the manuscript. I'm not sure whether this helps Google Scholar work it all out. But it should help readers work out which is the canonical reference.